# Hubtile.Title upside down

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I'm using the HubTile control from the silverlight toolkit and somehow the title is displayed upside down in my own app, but also in the preview. See Screenshots below.

I'm generating the tile from code behind and adding it to a WrapPanel control:

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.SetSource(stream);

var hubtile = new HubTile()
{
    Source = bitmap,
    Height = AppConfig.TileHeight,
    Width = AppConfig.TileWidth,
    Background = App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush,
    Margin = new Thickness(5),
    IsFrozen = true,
    Title = "Lorem Ipsum"
};

wpTiles.Children.Add(hubtile);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is caused by image absence. Source codes of `Silverlight Toolkit` are available to public, so you can fix that if will not find a workaround

Comment: Create a style to do this, very simple, see: http://studentguru.gr/b/kokyri/archive/2011/12/03/hubtiles-with-transparent-images.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upside down part is the back of the tile.
It is visible because you haven't set a background to the front of the tile.

Be sure to set the background of the front and back of the tile (to something that isn't transparent) to avoid this scenario.

Comment: I'm using a png with a transparent background as the source. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: @Dave yes. Use an image without transparency.